# ‘tell a story’ or ‘tell the story’ in a single sentence

Tags: articles, definite-article, indefinite-article

The single sentence:

> The novel tells the story of a salesman.

Can I say:

> The novel tells a story of a salesman?

I chose **a** story, but the answer is **the** story.

Answer (score 2):

Both sentences are fine. They have *slightly* different meanings.

The phrase "the story of [some person]" implies that I'm talking about the most important or most significant story about that person. For example, if I say "the story of Bill Gates," I mean the story of how Bill Gates co-founded Microsoft and became the richest person in the world. On the other hand, if I say "a story of Bill Gates," I mean *some* story which involves Bill Gates, but not necessarily the most significant story about Bill Gates.

So, if you write

> The novel tells the story of a salesman.

then you're probably telling the story of the salesman's entire life, or the story of how he became a successful salesman, or something like that.

On the other hand, if you write

> The novel tells a story of a salesman.

then you're telling *some* story about the salesman, but not necessarily a particularly important story.

You can also say "a story about a salesman" instead of "a story of a salesman"; I think "about" sounds a little more natural than "of" in this context. However, you can't say "the story about a salesman" instead of "the story of a salesman," because the phrase used to refer to a person's life story is "the story *of*," not "the story *about*."

Comment: This, ladies and gentlemen, is a good answer.

Comment: @BenKovitz Second that. This answer makes it clear that both the definite and indefinite articles are fine in the sentence at issue and gives an excellent explanation. This answer should have been accepted.

Answer (score 1):

The definite article (the) is used for the nouns you are sure of, definite of.

By putting *the* novel itself means that the context is **clear** and they are referring to the specific novel. Furthermore, when it is clear which *novel* they are talking about, and when *that* novel becomes specific, **the** story is also already defined. That is why, you put **the.**

In short, in the given sentence, both of them are defined - the novel and the story of someone.