# This is a/the story of a little girl

Tags: articles, definite-article, indefinite-article

What's the difference between "a" and "the" in the following sentence?

> This is **a/the** story of a little girl in a wheelchair called Susan who laughs, sings, flies and swings – just like every other little girl.

Comment: _The story of [name]_ usually implies an account of who the person is, what kind of life they have led or the most significant thing that has happened to them. _A story of/about [name]_ could be just one of a character's many adventures.

Comment: [Both forms occur](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=story+of+the+girl+who%2Cstory+of+a+girl+who&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cstory%20of%20the%20girl%20who%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cstory%20of%20a%20girl%20who%3B%2Cc0), but *story of **a** girl who* has occurred significantly more often in print than *story of **the** girl who*. Having said that, it would rarely make much if any difference to the meaning. Let's face it, even *the story of **a** woman who gave birth to Jesus* is "acceptable", even though there was obviously ***only ever one***.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [‘tell a story’ or ‘tell the story’ in a single sentence.](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/226365/tell-a-story-or-tell-the-story-in-a-single-sentence) Also [The|A story|ies about James and Susie?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/20715/thea-storyies-about-james-and-susie)